# In "Angels Take Manhattan", why couldn't The Doctor just shatter/laser-cut the angel's stone arm and release River?

Tags: doctor-who, weeping-angels, river-song

I mean, come on. With technologies beyond all of humanity's, he couldn't find a way to wriggle out of this one and "rewrite" time? 
**scoffs** definitely a plot hole; the writers wanted it to seem inescapable so that later on we easily buy into why and how

> Rory and Amelia left the show. How it *must've been* Amelia's farewell

because River *had* to break her wrist *just because* they read their futures. so it seems that time *could absolutely not* be re-written.

But I'm prepared to stand corrected. Anyone?

Comment: I too think it's a plot hole; the fact that Amy later wrote about it proves nothing: people can write all sorts of nonsense, which doesn't make that nonsense a fixed point in time.

Comment: On another hand, given the [fluent nature of Doctor Who canon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/109469/which-doctor-who-works-are-canon), it's hard to blame authors for "plot holes", since it's not their fault that latter authors sometimes just override everything.

Comment: You make a pretty big assumption that it's stone. Nobody ever said a weeping angel was made of mere stone, even while appearing to be a statue.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo yes, they did. Back when they were introduced, in *Blink*, the Doctor says "they literally turn to stone". Their fundamental premise *rests* on their genuinely being stone while observed.

Comment: @DoctorTwo *Blink* states "it's a fact of their biology", indicating it has nothing to do with how much "food" they've been getting. If Moffat has the same character claim otherwise later as though he's always thought that way, this rather proves the point about inconsistency in the question.

Comment: @Darael even if they were _not_ stone, there is such a thing as a laser cutter or something. The doctor could have used ANYTHING to cut that arm off. She didn't have to BREAK her wrist.

Comment: @DoctorTwo don't be ridiculous, of course it is. But turning literally to stone when observed being an involuntary fact of their biology would imply it's not alterable by other aspects of their biology like how much they're feeding. If it were only applicable to starving angels there would be no reason for the Doctor to have phrased it as he did.

Comment: @strawberries Aye. But Doctor Two and Disturbed Neo appear to be arguing that Angels are (or may be?) essentially indestructible except by major dimensional aberration, which I don't think is supported by the show, at least until Moffat started being inconsistent about his own monsters.

Comment: @DoctorTwo on the contrary, I implied that one fact of their biology is not inherently a consequence of the state of another aspect of their biology.

Comment: @DoctorTwo we've been told "you can't kill a stone" (in a rather throwaway fashion), which is not quite the same thing as "they can't be harmed". We've also seen the characters treat the situation in the question as though breaking the angel was *physically* (as opposed to in the sense of timeline-maintenance) just as possible as breaking River's, we've seen weapons designed to target flesh have little impact on stone, and we've seen the same crash that an angel survived have little effect on the ship's other contents either.

Comment: (we also know that the angel aboard the *Byzantium* was not quantum-locked at the time because there were no other living things aboard to observe it, which makes it irrelevant to the durability of locked angels)

Comment: @Gallifreyan on yet another hand that applies rather less *here*, since the Angels have only ever been written by one writer who we can reasonably hold to the standard of keeping his *own monsters* consistent.

Comment: @DoctorTwo Doesn't follow: so did the (organic and comparatively squishy) forest inside the ship. Regardless, the durability while *not in stone form* is utterly irrelevant to the durability of the one that *was* stone holding River.

Comment: So... 4 years later, nobody has a definite answer, lol. I hate that I can’t know the flippin answer

Answer (score 10):

An Angel survived crashing into a planet during the events of the Byzantium.

> There's one survivor. There's a thing in the belly of that ship that can't ever die.
>
> ***The Time of Angels***

What makes you think you can destroy or damage a Weeping Angel?

We've seen them quantum locked and wiped from time but never physically harmed.

Later in the *Time of Angels* the Doctor tells us they've lost form due to being starved for centuries.

> RIVER: But there was only one Angel on the ship. Just the one, I swear.
>
> AMY: Could they have been here already?
>
> DOCTOR: The Aplans. What happened? How did they die out?
>
> RIVER: Nobody knows.
>
> DOCTOR: We know.
>
> OCTAVIAN: They don't look like Angels.
>
> AMY: And they're not fast. You said they were fast. They should have had us by now.
>
> DOCTOR: Look at them. They're dying, losing their form. They must have been down here for centuries, starving.
>
> AMY: Losing their image?
>
> DOCTOR: And their image is their power. Power. Power!
>
> AMY: Doctor?
>
> DOCTOR: Don't you see? All that radiation spilling out the drive burn. The crash of the Byzantium wasn't an accident, it was a rescue mission for the Angels. We're in the middle of an army, and it's waking up.

Comment: The fact that the angels in that same episode started in bad shape suggests strongly that they *can* be damaged.

Comment: they're also heavily worn, the implication being that *due* to the starvation they couldn't (so to speak) self-repair, not that the external damage was caused directly by the starvation.

Comment: yes, they repaired once they had the radiation, which is to say *once they were no longer starving*: without an energy source they were unable to do so. The 51st-century weapons weren't exactly optimised for damaging stone, which is enough to explain that. And I interpreted that as their having been unable to maintain form (by the ongoing self-repair typical of living things) because of starvation.

Comment: we don't really know whether or not they all survived the crash or whether or not they were "unscathed", nobody did a body count as far as I know, so we cant say for sure. Since "it's a fact of their biology" to turn into stone when looked at, then that's what they are when people look at them: stone. And you can break stone. furthermore, the weeping angel which held River was weak.

Comment: @DoctorTwo anything that's actually stone (aggregates of minerals and/or mineraloids) will have a breaking stress. Even azbantium (*Heaven Sent*) and Dalekanium (*Remembrance of the Daleks*, among many many others) are breakable, and in any case were the angels some exotic stone like that when locked, we can reasonably assume it would have been mentioned rather than the generic "stone".

Comment: Another thing, in The Angels Take Manhattan, the mob boss guy had **tortured** the angel he held captive, so they *can* be harmed. In the episode, River remarks that the angel looks badly damaged (as they can be badly damaged), to which the mob guy replies I wanted to know if it could feel pain (which implies that he's the one who inflicted the said damage). To which River replies, "you realise it's screaming?" Which implies that not only do they feel pain, they can also call the others for aid.

Answer (score 1):

The doctor only has a sonic screwdriver, not a laser beam. They would state that bringing and setting the equipment would take time.

Agreed on the fact that this episode tries do manage Angel related time paradoxes, but the "hey we will trigger it because we love each other" part breaks the plot...

Comment: As long as they stared at the thing, they had all the time in the world. granted, they were looking for Rory, but it took them several minutes to locate Rory anyway, that time could have been spent in getting a laser beam from the tardis, for example. Like, they could've managed, especially when the alternative was River breaking her own wrist.